# In C#, is there a default way to create a new list with an item added, without modifying the original list?

Tags: c#, list, append

Basicially an appending function, where if I give one list and an item, it returns a totally new list with that item added. I'm not asking how to do it, I want to know if there's already an efficient way to do so built into the .Net source. Obviously I could just do something like this;

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();
newList.AddRange(oldList);
newList.Add(newElem);
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: ImmutableList is specifically for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>(oldList) { newElem };
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution for me, since it doesn't require the installation of any nuget packages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, immutable collections. https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/23/using-immutable-collections-for-thread-safe-read-only-operations-in-net/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time/

Available through nuget package "System.Collections.Immutable ".

From the site:

> What are immutable collections? Over time, the .NET Framework has
>   added many features that made concurrent programming a lot easier.
>   This started with the introduction of the thread pool, got a lot more
>   powerful with the task-based model and the Task Parallel Library
>   (TPL), and was improved even more by the addition of the async and
>   await language keywords. While creating and running concurrently is
>   easier than ever, one of the fundamental problems still exists:
>   mutable shared state. Reading from multiple threads is typically very
>   easy, but once the state needs to be updated, it gets a lot harder,
>   especially in designs that require locking. An alternative to locking
>   is making use of immutable state. Immutable data structures are
>   guaranteed to never change and can thus be passed freely between
>   different threads without worrying about stepping on somebody else’s
>   toes.

As others have answered it is possible do this without Immutable Collections. If you're the only one working on the project, or if you are sure you have control about the source than that might do. But an error is easy to make, especially when there a lots of modifications to your lists. Using Immutable Collections you don't have to worry, or worry less, about these kind of errors.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't desired for SO because links can break down the line. In addition to links, please also provide the relevant information from the link so that the answer can stand on its own in the even the links do break.

Comment: They don't seem to be default in the .Net libraries, I can't seem to import it.

Comment: A little bit of looking reveals that it requires a nuget package to be installed. I really don't think it's a good idea to install a whole nuget package just to compress two lines of code. Is there an implementation in the default libraries?

Comment: @Maurdekye it's available through nugget, see update

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using linq.

```
var list = new []{1, 3, 4}.Concat(new []{6}).ToList() // list now contains 1,3,4,6
```

You can also define an overload for Concat that takes a single element so you don't have to create the list with one element.

Comment: or `Enumerable.Repeat(6,1)` to avoid that array.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid resizing, involving the creation of a new internal array and an array copy operation, I would create the new list by specifying its new initial capacity, but otherwise still use your approach:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>(oldList.Count + 1);
newList.AddRange(oldList);
newList.Add(newElem);
```

A totally different approach would be to borrow a concept from functional languages, where linked lists are used. Instead of creating a copy of a list and adding one item, new items are added in front of the list and a reference to the first item is returned as a reference to the remainder of the list. The list can only be enumerated from this item to the end. This is thread safe, since a thread never sees newly added items.